# Having trouble with horizontal scroll bar on my site

Tags: html, css, margin, padding, horizontal-scrolling

Hi there I am having trouble with a horizontal scroll bar appearing on my site, I have no idea why it is appearing. It only showed up when I was playing around with the footer however even after removing the footer it was still there.

The site I am working on is http://tritorial.com.au any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this in your `css`

```
body {
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- if you are using w3css, make sure the width is 100% including the margins and padding
- try adding `clear:both;` and `overflow:hidden;` to some items in your css.